# How to disable back button behavior?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to create a pin entry. I want the numeric keypad to be visible always. The problem is, I cannot override hardware button behavior which dismisses the keyboard. `OnBackButtonPressed` isn't entered when the button is pressed for dismissing the keyboard. What can I do? ()

Comment: A naive solution would be to create your own keypad. Lot of apps do that (including Google's Duo).

Comment: that's just stupid. sooooooo stupid. shame, google, shame.

Comment: @Shaishav you mean creating a custom Keyboard or adding a grid at the bottom of the page that will _act_ like a keyboard?

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: sorry, which one?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant adding a grid of buttons at the bottom like [here](http://updato.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Google-Duo-3.png).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option for you is use an specific keyboard.
Maybe you can use this Xamarin component https://components.xamarin.com/view/TestComponent